# Capture audio from Microphone without playing it back

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, microphone

I am trying to use a microphone and process the audio captured. I managed to do all that, but I have a problem... My audio captured is automatically played to the user, and I don't want that.

```
    audioSrc.clip = Microphone.Start(null, true, 1000, 44100);
    while (!(Microphone.GetPosition(null) > 0)) { }
    audioSrc.Play();
```

I tried to disable the audio listener and lower the volume of the audio source, but that didn't work.

Anyone knows how I can capture audio without playing it back?

EDIT 1:

```
void Start()
{
    GameObject a = new GameObject("AudioSource");
    audioSrc = a.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    Instantiate(a);

    string deviceName = Microphone.devices[0];
    audioSrc.clip = Microphone.Start(deviceName, true, 1000, 44100);
    audioSrc.volume = 0;
    while (!(Microphone.GetPosition(null) > 0)) { }

    audioSrc.Play();
}

void Update()
{
    audioSrc.GetSpectrumData(spectrum, 0, FFTWindow.BlackmanHarris);
    frq = findPitch(spectrum);
    txtFreq.text = "Hz: " + frq;
    trigger.update(Time.deltaTime, frq);
}
```

Comment: hi Lulas, are you there?  you need to TICK an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Anyone knows how I can capture audio without playing it back?

There are two methods to do this:

**1**.Set the volume to a very low number. ***This cannot be 0***. The value of `0.001f` is totally fine.

```
audioSrc.volume = 0.001f;
```

Works in the Editor. Not tested on any other platform except on Windows. Use method 2 if there is a problem.

---

**2**.Use AudioMixer to handle it

If setting the volume to `0.001f` did not completely mute the audio then use `AudioMixer` to fix it.

**A**.Create AudioMixer. *Assets* ---> *Create* ---> *Audio Mixer* and name is *"MicMixer"*.

**B**.Create new Group under the Mixer and name it "MuteMic".

**C**.Change the attenuation of that *"MuteMic"* group to `-80`.

**D**.Drag that  *"MuteMic"* group to your Mic's AudioSource's **Output** slot. That's it. The `GetOutputData` function properly without any sound coming out from the speaker.

Animated gif for this:

[image]

Comment: Method number 2 doesn't seem to work when using the `OnAudioFilterRead()` method instead of the `GetOutputData` function, sadly.