# GetOutputData returning 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nuget

My purpose is just to get the voice input level

I searched and found this code - but it always return 0 whatever my voice input level - I keep shouting , but always return 0

here's the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mic : MonoBehaviour {
        public float sens = 100;
        public float loud = 0;
        AudioSource audio;

        void Start()
        {
            audio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
            audio.clip = Microphone.Start (null, true, 10, 44100);
            audio.loop = true;
            audio.mute = true;
            while (!(Microphone.GetPosition (null) > 0)) {}
            audio.Play ();
        }

        void Update()
        {
            loud = GetAvgVol () * sens;
            Debug.Log (loud); //always debug 0
        }

        float GetAvgVol()
        {
            float [] data = new float[256];
            float a = 0;
            audio.GetOutputData (data, 0);
            foreach(float s in data)
            {
                a += Mathf.Abs (s);
            }
            return a / 256;
        }
}
```

how to achieve my purpose inside unity?

- if there's any library/plugin to facilitate this process , it will be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are no errors thrown by Unity in the Editor, these are the reasons why `AudioSource.GetOutputData` may return 0:

**1**.The `AudioSource` volume is set `0`.

For example, `AudioSourceInstance.volume = 0`.

**2**.The `AudioSource` is muted is set `true`.

For example, `AudioSourceInstance.mute = true;`

**3**.There is no audio playing in the AudioSource.

For example, `AudioSourceInstance.Play ()` is not called,  `AudioSourceInstance.Pause()` is called or `AudioSourceInstance.Stop()` has been called on that `AudioSource`.

**4**.The audio file or mic is silent.

---

In your case, the cause is **#2**.

If you just want to capture data from the mic without playing it back live then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48647204/3785314) answer that mentioned two ways to do this

Also, I suggest you replace `return a / 256;` with `return a / 256f;` in your `GetAvgVol` function.

Comment: Your answer helped me too much - everything is working now

Answer (score 1):

I'm not on a machine with unity at the moment but your input level seems like its fine.

The problem might be

```
        audio.clip = Microphone.Start (null, true, 10, 44100);
```

You are setting the deviceName to NULL, try putting in a device name that you can discover with Microphone.devices

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone-devices.html

Comment: Yes , I changed it to => audio.clip = Microphone.Start (Microphone.devices[0], true, 10, 44100); , which Microphone.devices[0] is the built-in microphone -- unfortunately it did not work

Comment: Does it not work in terms of the mic doesnt open / record or the input level is still reported as 0?

Looking at some old code where I was using mic input, I had explicity called .ToString()

Maybe try Microphone.devices[0].ToString()

Comment: Microphone.devices is array of string , so Microphone.devices[0] is actually a string

Comment: @AboMohsen I thought so. I guess I was just hoping I explicity called it for a reason :p

feel free to check out my implementation of microphone input for unity if you are still stuck

https://github.com/rampartisan/DolbyTechChallenge/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/MicrophoneInput.cs