# How to read the data from AudioClip using PCMReaderCallback when the former is created by Microphone.Start in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

How can I change the code below to use the PCMReaderCallback to read data from the audio clip created by `Microphone.Start`?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string m_deviceName = null;
    private AudioClip m_audioClip;

    void Start()
    {
        bool loop = true;
        int lengthSec = 10;
        int frequency = 44100;

        m_audioClip = Microphone.Start(m_deviceName, loop, lengthSec, frequency);
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        Microphone.End(m_deviceName);
        m_audioClip = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the Microphone API with `PCMReaderCallback`. This is because `PCMReaderCallback` is registered by passing the PCMReaderCallback function to the `AudioClip.Create` function which returns a new `AudioClip`. Unity's `Microphone.Start` function returns `AudioClip` but it doesn't take  `PCMReaderCallback` as argument.

If this is not a Microphone but a simple audio clip then you could with the example below:

```
public int lengthSamples = 400;
public int channels = 2;
public int frequency = 16000;

AudioSource adSource;

void Start()
{
    adSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    AudioClip clip = AudioClip.Create("clip", lengthSamples, channels, frequency, true, OnAudioRead);
    adSource.clip = clip;
    adSource.Play();
}

//PCMReaderCallback callback
void OnAudioRead(float[] data)
{

}
```

---

If you just want to read the audio data from the Mic, you can still use [`OnAudioFilterRead`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnAudioFilterRead.html) or the [`AudioSource.clip.GetData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.GetData.html) function. Below is an example for `OnAudioFilterRead`.

```
string m_deviceName = null;
AudioSource adSource;

void Start()
{
    adSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    bool loop = true;
    int lengthSec = 10;
    int frequency = 44100;

    AudioClip clip = Microphone.Start(m_deviceName, loop, lengthSec, frequency);
    adSource.clip = clip;
    while (!(Microphone.GetPosition(null) > 0)) { }

    adSource.Play();
}

void OnAudioFilterRead(float[] data, int channels)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Two more questions. Why `while (!(Microphone.GetPosition(null) > 0)) { }`? How to avoid the microphone input to be played back?

Comment: Without `while (!(Microphone.GetPosition(null) > 0))` there can be a bug in your code. For example, trying to access the data from mic may return 0. This is a problem I see on this site all the time so you have to wait until the pos is >1. You may not run into it but many that will use your app will. Also that can cause audioclip to not even play at-all. For your second question, see my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37787343/3785314) answer.